# Looking for a NBD C/S for windows (Network Block Device)

Tags: networking, storage, io, block-device

Where can I find a NBD Server (and also a Client)
that I can use in windows 10?

(preferably FOSS source code for inspect/change/compile/...)

Been looking for a while on the internet 
and seems that no one overcome this task...

Comment: Probably easier to run it in a virtual/container.

Comment: Yep... but it is a huge annoyance--- native windows binaries would be a charm...

Comment: [nbdkit has a Windows port](https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2020/08/20/nbdkit-now-ported-to-windows/) now and [there are binaries here](http://oirase.annexia.org/nbdkit/).

Comment: thanks Rich... i'll try it... :-))

Answer (score 4):

You can use Starwind vsan for block device over iSCSI. No special client is required, default built-in MS iSCSI Initiator can be used.
[www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free](http://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free)

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for,,, a lean+and+mean remote block device for use even in WinPE... I would prefer not to use a 'truck' to transport just one brick!!!

Comment: being iSCSI will it only export entire disks or can it export single partitions?

Comment: it can export physical disk as RAW device or virtual disk located on partition